# Kusto Query Pipeline Query

Tags: azure, pipeline, azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I am trying to create another column from a pipeline runs data using Azure data explorer/Kusto queries. I am very new to Kusto and not sure  how to go about that.  Goal is for each customer,

1. If previous run failed and last run failed get difference of days/hours between failures.
2. If previous run succeeded and last run failed, get difference of days/hours between the events
3. If previous event failed and last event succeeded, then ignore.

Dataset

```
Customers   PipelineType    PipelineState    TimeStamp
CustomerA   PipelineA   Succes               2021-08-13 12:59:03.0073653
CustomerA   PipelineA   Fail                 2021-08-13 09:59:03.0124853
CustomerA   PipelineB   Succes               2021-08-13 11:56:03.0151948
CustomerA   Pipeline B  Fail                 2021-08-12 17:56:03.0019445
CustomerA   Pipeline C  Succes               2021-08-13 13:16:03.0015617
CustomerA   Pipeline C  Fail                 2021-07-30 21:52:03.0157372
CustomerB   PipelineA   Succes               2021-08-13 12:59:03.0073331
CustomerB   PipelineA   Succes               2021-08-13 12:57:03.0099138
CustomerB   PipelineB   Fail                 2021-07-30 03:33:03.0123262
CustomerB   Pipeline B  Succes               2021-08-13 13:16:03.0015297
CustomerB   Pipeline C  Fail                 2021-08-13 12:57:03.0099499
CustomerB   Pipeline C  Succes               2021-08-13 13:16:03.0016348
CustomerC   PipelineA   Succes               2021-08-13 13:16:03.0016999
CustomerC   PipelineA   Succes               2021-08-13 12:59:03.0074113
CustomerC   PipelineB   Succes               2021-08-13 10:56:03.0075546
CustomerC   Pipeline B  Fail                 2021-08-11 06:54:03.0118628
CustomerC   Pipeline C  Fail                 2021-08-13 13:16:03.0016233
CustomerC   Pipeline C  Fail                 2021-08-13 12:59:03.0072337
``
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the requirements correctly, you could sort your data set and then use the `case()` and `prev()` functions.

For example:

```
datatable(customer:string, PipelineType:string, PipelineState:string, TimeStamp:datetime)
[
    'CustomerA', 'Pipeline A', 'Fail',    datetime(2021-08-13 12:59:03.0073653),
    'CustomerA', 'Pipeline A', 'Fail',    datetime(2021-08-13 09:59:03.0124853),
    'CustomerA', 'Pipeline B', 'Success', datetime(2021-08-13 11:56:03.0151948),
    'CustomerA', 'Pipeline B', 'Fail',    datetime(2021-08-12 17:56:03.0019445),
    'CustomerA', 'Pipeline C', 'Success', datetime(2021-08-13 13:16:03.0015617),
    'CustomerA', 'Pipeline C', 'Fail',    datetime(2021-07-30 21:52:03.0157372),
    'CustomerB', 'Pipeline A', 'Fail',    datetime(2021-08-13 12:59:03.0073331),
    'CustomerB', 'Pipeline A', 'Success', datetime(2021-08-13 12:57:03.0099138),
    'CustomerB', 'Pipeline B', 'Fail',    datetime(2021-07-30 03:33:03.0123262),
    'CustomerB', 'Pipeline B', 'Success', datetime(2021-08-13 13:16:03.0015297),
    'CustomerB', 'Pipeline C', 'Fail',    datetime(2021-08-13 12:57:03.0099499),
    'CustomerB', 'Pipeline C', 'Success', datetime(2021-08-13 13:16:03.0016348),
    'CustomerC', 'Pipeline A', 'Fail',    datetime(2021-08-13 13:16:03.0016999),
    'CustomerC', 'Pipeline A', 'Fail',    datetime(2021-08-13 12:59:03.0074113),
    'CustomerC', 'Pipeline B', 'Success', datetime(2021-08-13 10:56:03.0075546),
    'CustomerC', 'Pipeline B', 'Fail',    datetime(2021-08-11 06:54:03.0118628),
    'CustomerC', 'Pipeline C', 'Fail',    datetime(2021-08-13 13:16:03.0016233),
    'CustomerC', 'Pipeline C', 'Fail',    datetime(2021-08-13 12:59:03.0072337),
]   
| order by customer asc, PipelineType asc, TimeStamp asc
| extend result = case(prev(customer) == customer and prev(PipelineType) == PipelineType and PipelineState == 'Fail', TimeStamp - prev(TimeStamp), timespan(null))
```

| customer | PipelineType | PipelineState | TimeStamp | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CustomerA | Pipeline A | Fail | 2021-08-13 09:59:03.0124853 |  |
| CustomerA | Pipeline A | Fail | 2021-08-13 12:59:03.0073653 | 02:59:59.9948800 |
| CustomerA | Pipeline B | Fail | 2021-08-12 17:56:03.0019445 |  |
| CustomerA | Pipeline B | Success | 2021-08-13 11:56:03.0151948 |  |
| CustomerA | Pipeline C | Fail | 2021-07-30 21:52:03.0157372 |  |
| CustomerA | Pipeline C | Success | 2021-08-13 13:16:03.0015617 |  |
| CustomerB | Pipeline A | Success | 2021-08-13 12:57:03.0099138 |  |
| CustomerB | Pipeline A | Fail | 2021-08-13 12:59:03.0073331 | 00:01:59.9974193 |
| CustomerB | Pipeline B | Fail | 2021-07-30 03:33:03.0123262 |  |
| CustomerB | Pipeline B | Success | 2021-08-13 13:16:03.0015297 |  |
| CustomerB | Pipeline C | Fail | 2021-08-13 12:57:03.0099499 |  |
| CustomerB | Pipeline C | Success | 2021-08-13 13:16:03.0016348 |  |
| CustomerC | Pipeline A | Fail | 2021-08-13 12:59:03.0074113 |  |
| CustomerC | Pipeline A | Fail | 2021-08-13 13:16:03.0016999 | 00:16:59.9942886 |
| CustomerC | Pipeline B | Fail | 2021-08-11 06:54:03.0118628 |  |
| CustomerC | Pipeline B | Success | 2021-08-13 10:56:03.0075546 |  |
| CustomerC | Pipeline C | Fail | 2021-08-13 12:59:03.0072337 |  |
| CustomerC | Pipeline C | Fail | 2021-08-13 13:16:03.0016233 | 00:16:59.9943896 |

---

**Update**: in reply to your comment - just add the appropriate filters.

For example:

```
datatable(customer:string, PipelineType:string, PipelineState:string, TimeStamp:datetime)
[
    'CustomerA', 'Pipeline A', 'Fail',    datetime(2021-08-13 12:59:03.0073653),
    'CustomerA', 'Pipeline A', 'Fail',    datetime(2021-08-13 09:59:03.0124853),
    'CustomerA', 'Pipeline B', 'Success', datetime(2021-08-13 11:56:03.0151948),
    'CustomerA', 'Pipeline B', 'Fail',    datetime(2021-08-12 17:56:03.0019445),
    'CustomerA', 'Pipeline C', 'Success', datetime(2021-08-13 13:16:03.0015617),
    'CustomerA', 'Pipeline C', 'Fail',    datetime(2021-07-30 21:52:03.0157372),
    'CustomerB', 'Pipeline A', 'Fail',    datetime(2021-08-13 12:59:03.0073331),
    'CustomerB', 'Pipeline A', 'Success', datetime(2021-08-13 12:57:03.0099138),
    'CustomerB', 'Pipeline B', 'Fail',    datetime(2021-07-30 03:33:03.0123262),
    'CustomerB', 'Pipeline B', 'Success', datetime(2021-08-13 13:16:03.0015297),
    'CustomerB', 'Pipeline C', 'Fail',    datetime(2021-08-13 12:57:03.0099499),
    'CustomerB', 'Pipeline C', 'Success', datetime(2021-08-13 13:16:03.0016348),
    'CustomerC', 'Pipeline A', 'Fail',    datetime(2021-08-13 13:16:03.0016999),
    'CustomerC', 'Pipeline A', 'Fail',    datetime(2021-08-13 12:59:03.0074113),
    'CustomerC', 'Pipeline B', 'Success', datetime(2021-08-13 10:56:03.0075546),
    'CustomerC', 'Pipeline B', 'Fail',    datetime(2021-08-11 06:54:03.0118628),
    'CustomerC', 'Pipeline C', 'Fail',    datetime(2021-08-13 13:16:03.0016233),
    'CustomerC', 'Pipeline C', 'Fail',    datetime(2021-08-13 12:59:03.0072337),
]   
| order by customer asc, PipelineType asc, TimeStamp asc
| where not((prev(customer) == customer and prev(PipelineType) == PipelineType and PipelineState == 'Success' and prev(PipelineState) == 'Fail') or 
            (prev(customer) == customer and prev(PipelineType) == PipelineType and PipelineState == 'Fail' and next(PipelineState) == 'Success'))
| extend result = case(prev(customer) == customer and prev(PipelineType) == PipelineType and PipelineState == 'Fail', TimeStamp - prev(TimeStamp), timespan(null))
```

| customer | PipelineType | PipelineState | TimeStamp | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CustomerA | Pipeline A | Fail | 2021-08-13 09:59:03.0124853 |  |
| CustomerA | Pipeline A | Fail | 2021-08-13 12:59:03.0073653 | 02:59:59.9948800 |
| CustomerA | Pipeline B | Fail | 2021-08-12 17:56:03.0019445 |  |
| CustomerA | Pipeline C | Fail | 2021-07-30 21:52:03.0157372 |  |
| CustomerB | Pipeline A | Success | 2021-08-13 12:57:03.0099138 |  |
| CustomerB | Pipeline A | Fail | 2021-08-13 12:59:03.0073331 | 00:01:59.9974193 |
| CustomerB | Pipeline B | Fail | 2021-07-30 03:33:03.0123262 |  |
| CustomerB | Pipeline C | Fail | 2021-08-13 12:57:03.0099499 |  |
| CustomerC | Pipeline A | Fail | 2021-08-13 12:59:03.0074113 |  |
| CustomerC | Pipeline A | Fail | 2021-08-13 13:16:03.0016999 | 00:16:59.9942886 |
| CustomerC | Pipeline B | Fail | 2021-08-11 06:54:03.0118628 |  |
| CustomerC | Pipeline C | Fail | 2021-08-13 12:59:03.0072337 |  |
| CustomerC | Pipeline C | Fail | 2021-08-13 13:16:03.0016233 | 00:16:59.9943896 |

Comment: Thanks Yoni for this. I had a similar query. I guess I was on the right path. I think what I am missing now is how to ignore if previous run  failed but current succeeds. For example Customer B, Pipeline B, pipeline failed 2021-07-30 but succeeded 2021-08-13. Is there a way not have this record in the output?